# Spinnaker: Added an account (Azure), but no region is populated

Tags: azure, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

Has anyone run into this issue where you add an account (Azure), but no region is populated when creating a new security group or load balancer?

The azure account was added with no errors (even checked logs, clouddriver, echo, etc.). Since there is no region found, this essentially blocks adding any of these objects.

Just for reference I used the Azure quickstart template to do an initial Spinnaker installation

See image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NGkR.jpg

Comment: Just fyi, I've tried running on different spinnaker version, 1.4.2 / 1.5.2 as well as on instances that were created from Azure quickstart templates, and from scratch.
In all cases, I eventually run in to the same blocking issue.

Comment: Also, the cloud provider was an Azure account (for Azure VM scale sets, not a Kubernetes cluster).

Comment: I am facing the same issue now

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround:

https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/2229#issuecomment-404161532

Apparently, you have to list the regions first in the Clouddriver config file...